# Remove a specific suffix from an array of strings separated by a special character

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to remove the ".(something)" suffix from the domain name field which is an array of strings separated by a pipe(|)

The data looks like below-

```
ID          domain
1        ab23c45|xyz167a.abc|d1ef76om.abc|rx08bj23
2        omg23hy5|xyz167a|ab23c45.xyz|jhy2ft3.def
```

The result should look like-

```
ID          domain
1        ab23c45|xyz167a|d1ef76om|rx08bj23
2        omg23hy5|xyz167a|ab23c45|jhy2ft3
```

Note: The suffix could be anything. Need a generic solution that works with any of the suffixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id,  
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(REGEXP_REPLACE(domain, r'\.\w+$', ''), '|')
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(domain, '|')) domain
  ) domain
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row id  domain   
1   1   ab23c45|xyz167a|d1ef76om|rx08bj23    
2   2   omg23hy5|xyz167a|ab23c45|jhy2ft3
```